# How to display certain amounts of PushPins on a Bing Map according to the zoom level?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps, pushpin

In my web application a PushPin represents a device located in a region, it displays PushPins on a Bing Map depending on two operations:

- One is that when the user wants to display of all the devices
  registered.
- The second one is when the sever sends a signal to the web site that 
  a particular device must be shown.

The thing is that there are several devices in a region and when the map is zoomed out at level 5 they all look quite messy.

Is there a way to limit the amount of exisiting PushPins displayed on a Bing Map depending on the zoom level? Like at level 5 only show one PushPin and on higher zoom level increase the amount displayed, so that at level 15 all existing PushPins are shown.

I tried the EnableShapeDisplayThreshold method, but it seems that only works for polylines and polygons, not PushPins.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to use is called clustering, it's grouping the marker (pushpins) depending on the level of zoom and current map view.

**Reference:**

Based on the method you're currently using (`EnableShapeDisplayThreshold`), I assume that you're using v6.3 so you should be able to use the `VEShapeLayer.SetClusteringConfiguration()` method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966930.aspx

**Sample code:**

Here in action : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980909.aspx

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.
I just have a quick question, is there a way to set a custom text on the clusters? and to pass the options for the clustering, do I only initialize an object like `VECustomIconSpecification icon = new VECustomIconSpecification(); icon.Image = 'myIcon.png'; VEClusteringOptions options = new VEClusteringOptions(icon, null);` ?

Comment: I tried to change the icon, but it doesn't seem to work, I'm doing this `var custom = "<div style='font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;border:solid 2px Black;background-color:Aqua;width:50px;'>Custom</div>";
    var icon = new VECustomIconSpecification();
    icon.CustomHTML = custom;
    icon.Image = '../Content/Image/icons/pin2.png';
    var options = new VEClusteringOptions(icon, null);`, based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb545007.aspx) link.
Is this correct?